# scrolling some part of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am developing an app. In which we are placing `UIScrollView` and buttons & images on `UIScrollView`.Images are at the bottom of the `UIScrollView` and Buttons are at top of the `UIScrollView`.

Problem is that I want to scroll only images not buttons. Is it possible to scroll only some part in `UIScrollView`. If possible how can we achieve it.

Any one can help or suggest with links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting the buttons on the UIScrollView, make the UIScrollView smaller and add the buttons to the same parent view as the UIScrollView.

Comment: Actually i coded like that only. But when i want to drag the image from scrollView to view, touch events are not working

Answer (score 0):

You can take another scrollview and add images on it. So that if you scroll the images your buttons will not move.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 scrollviews, one for button & one for images. Then set scrolling disabled for the one with buttons.